# Node js query multiple collections in Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, join, google-cloud-firestore

I want to join 2 collections in Cloud Firestore database. How to implement it using Node.js?

Comment: you should combine 2 observable stream in your frontend using rxjs or ngrx

Comment: You may be interested by this article https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-combined-two-firestore-queries-to-simulate-a-logical-or-query-27d28a43cb2d

Answer (score 2):

As @AndreiTigau mentioned in his answer, you cannot join two queries in Firestore. This is because queries in Firestore are shallow, they only get items from the collection that the query is run against. However, if your collections are actually subcollections and have the **same** name, you can then use [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query):

> A collection group consists of all collections with the same ID. By default, queries retrieve results from a single collection in your database. Use a collection group query to retrieve documents from a collection group instead of from a single collection.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to join queries in Firestore. If you want to combine the data from two documents, you will have to query them individually, then mix the results in the way you wish.